# Having different items in top and side menu

Tags: magento, sidebar

I am currently working with Magento 2.1.1 and have the Sebwite sidebar (https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar) working along with the original Luma top menu.

The problem is that when I change the top menu's items, the sidebar will do the same. So, both seem to be configured as "root menu".
What I want to achieve is 2 menus containing different items.

I haven't been able to find the solution here or elsewhere on google. Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

this extension shows categories and child's on the side bar. if you wand to show side bar menu and it is different from top menu, this extension is not useful for you.
you should use sidebar menu extensions